# In what categories does the "classical" notion of function make sense?

Tags: functions, category-theory

I'm new to category theory, and I often struggle to choose the right level of abstraction when working with categories. I also found that many textbooks are rather inconsistent in their conventions with regards to the terminology (eg. they often interchangeably use terms like *epimorphism* and *surjection*, etc). So I wondered what's a minimal set of requirements on a category so that it makes sense to say that morphism are functions? How about Abelian categories?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The notion you are looking for is probably that of a [concrete category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category).  A concrete category is a category that is embedded in the category of sets; thus its objects are associated with actual sets, and its morphisms are associated with actual functions.

Comment: Top and Ab are perhaps two of the most concrete categories out there (after Set, anyway). But neither satisfies that epi = surjection.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: $Ab$ certainly satisfies it.

Comment: @Berci: I thought that the identity from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Q$ is an epimorphism. No?

Comment: Not in the category of Abelian groups. For rings or monoids (according to the other answer), it is indeed an epimorphism. In an Abelian category, a mono and epi morphism must be isomorphism. (Specifically we can take e.g. the quotient map and the zero map $\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ to obtain the same composition $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.)

Answer (score 4):

Beware that even in conrete categories the terms *epimorphism* and *surjection* are **not** interchangeable.

For example, consider

- the category **Mon** where objects are monoids and morphisms their algebraic homomorphisms
- and the forgetful functor making it concrete being the obvious $U: \mathrm{Mon} \to \mathrm{Set}$.

Now the embedding morphism $m: (\mathbb{Z}, \cdot, 1) \to (\mathbb{Q}, \cdot, 1)$ is a monomorphism *and* epimorphism as can be seen by some small, but tedious calculations. However, the associated actual function given by $U(m): \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is obviously not an epimorphism in Set. Notably, in Set the terms epimorphism and surjection really coincide — at least with AoC.

Comment: (Not an answer, but too long for a comment.)